# Pushing files from one Git repository to another

Tags: git, repository

I have 2 Git repositories with basically the same structure, but repository B has only some of the contents of repository A.

Repository A has newer commits that I need to push to B (but only the necessary files).

I have so far git clone'd the repositories to my local workstation. How should I replace the necessary files in repository B with files from repository A?

My naive attempt was `git mv /A/source/* /B/source/` which resulted in:

```
fatal: /B/source/: '/B/source/' is outside repository
```

Since I'm fairly new to git, I'm not 100% sure what I should be trying to achieve. I'll try and explain the context: We have active development going on in repository A. Repository B is currently for a third party to access parts of the content (they only need parts of it). Repository A has version 1.6, B has 1.4. So my goal is to push the necessary new content to B. I guess this would be commiting the commits made to A during 1.5 and 1.6 to B?

Comment: You just want to replace the files?  Not redo the commits or anything like that?

Comment: Since I'm fairly new to git, I'm not 100% sure what I should be trying to achieve. I'll try and explain the context: We have active development going on in repository A. Repository B is currently for a third party to access parts of the content (they only need parts of it). Repository A has version 1.6, B has 1.4. So my goal is to push the new content to B. Not sure what would be appropriate in this scenario @ThomasStringer

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable way to do this, I think, is to transfer the actual commits themselves. Use `git format-patch` to pull the commits from `A` which are not on `B`, or vice versa, and write them out to `.patch` files.

Then, in the other repo, use `git apply` to apply the `.patch` file commits to that repo. If there are conflicts you will have an opportunity to resolve them.

This is basically the same as "cherry-picking" commits, but across repositories rather than across branches.

(You can also use `git am` instead of `git apply` if you want, it's only a bit different.)

Comment: Thanks! Will be trying this out in a test environment for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

What we ended up doing was:

```
git rm /B/<files_to_replace> 

cp /A/<necessary_files> /B/

git add ...
```

This might not be the correct way to do it, but we were in a bit of a hurry and it'll get the job done for now. Thanks for the help! :)